# Faulty representation of spacy tags (before and after tokenization)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, tags, spacy

Does anyone know whether this kind of output is normal or harmless (for subsequent computations with the tags pandas DF column) when using spacy on a pandas DF (see "faulty representation...")?

**Code for converting DF text column ("fulltext") to spacy-tokenized text column:**

```
df["text_tokenized"] = df["fulltext"].apply(lambda x: [y.text for y in sp_model(x)])
df["text_tokenized"] = df["text_tokenized"].apply(' '.join)
```

**Code for converting DF tokenized_text column to spacy tags:**

```
df['TAG'] = df['text_tokenized'].apply(lambda x: [y.tag_ for y in  sp_model(x)])
df['TAG'] = df['TAG'].apply(' '.join)
```

I have similarly added columns for spacy dependencies, lemmas, and pos-tags. Those look just fine in the output in jupyter notebook, but for some reason, the spacy tags do not look right. I'm not sure what is going on: I think I have deleted non-ASCII characters because I thought it might have something to do with that. What baffles me is that it only occurs in some instances, definitely not all of them.

[image: faulty visual representation of spacy tags in pandas DF]

[image: Instance of correct spacy tag representation]

Answer (score 0):

According to a detailed extraction the data stored in the DF should be fine. It looks like it's just an output issue in the notebook.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjigF.png)

Edit: It is a mathjax problem in the output of the notebooks: since the original text data and spacy tags include signs like "$", mathjax assumes the following characters to be mathematical equations and attempts to convert them, resulting in a strange text output. Mathjax is enabled by default, regardless whether you are dealing with numeric or text output. I found most of this info here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/4817